# Trigger a job from another project with specified .yaml file through API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My initial problem is that I want to use `environment` keyword in a trigger job, but as of now you cannot do that in Gitlab CI/CD. As a workaround there is a way to do that for multu-project trigger job - you can do an API call as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipeline_triggers.html#trigger-a-pipeline-with-a-token). The problem is, accroding to this doc, you cannot pass a .yaml filename within this call, but you can if you describe job as trigger job ([example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline#use-a-child-pipeline-configuration-file-in-a-different-project))

My question is - is there a way to trigger job through API and use non default .yaml, but a specified one?